# Find a ruler in Taxicab plane

Tags: geometry, metric-geometry

> In the Taxicab Plane, find a ruler $f$ with $f(P)=0$ and $f(Q)>0$ for
>   the given pair $P$ and $Q$:
>
> $1. \ P = (2,3), Q=(2,-5)$
>
> $2. \ P= (2,3), Q = (4,0).$

The definition of ruler is

**Ruler**: Let $l$ be a line in an incidence geometry. Assume that there is a distance function $d$. A function $f: l \to \mathbb{R}$ is a ruler for $l$ if $f$ is a bijection and for each pair of points $P$ and $Q$ on $l$ we have $|f(P) - f(Q)| = d(P,Q)$. Where $f(P)$ is called the coordinate of $P$ with respect to $f$.

I am not sure how to do this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the taxicab metric, $d(P,Q)=|2-2|+|3-(-5)|=8$. The line connecting these two points is $$\ell\equiv\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,|\,x=2\}.$$ We have the the requirement that $$|f(P)-f(Q)|=|0-f(Q)|=|f(Q)|=d(P,Q)=8.$$ Therefore, either $f(Q)=8$ or $f(Q)=-8$. But we need $f(Q)>0$, so $f(Q)=8$. We can then extend $f(\cdot)$ onto the whole line $\ell$ as follows:
   \begin{align*}
   f(x,y)=3-y\quad\forall (x,y)\in\ell.
   \end{align*}
   You can check that $f$ is a bijection between the line $\ell$ and $\mathbb R$, and the definition of $f(\cdot)$ makes it apparent that $f(P)=f(2,3)=3-3=0$ and $f(Q)=f(2,-5)=3-(-5)=8$, as desired. Finally, if $P'=(p_1',p_2')$ and $Q'=(q_1',q_2')$ are another pair of points on the line $\ell$, then we have $p_1'=q_1'=2$ (with $q_1'\in\mathbb R$ and $q_2'\in \mathbb R$ being unrestricted) and also 
   \begin{align*}
   |f(P')-f(Q')|=&\,|f(p_1',p_2')-f(q_1',q_2')|=|f(2,p_2')-f(2,q_2')|\\=&\,|(3-p_2')-(3-q_2')|=|q_2'-p_2'|=d((p_1',p_2'),(q_1',q_2'))=d(P',Q'),\end{align*}
   since we are using the taxicab metric.

The second one can be solved using a similar reasoning, but finding the equation for the line $\ell$ connecting $P$ and $Q$ requires some more effort.

Comment: You wrote this with great clarity! Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Alex My pleasure, thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Triple_sec, I found the second line to be $y=(-3/2)x+6$ but how can I find $f( \dot\ )$? That satisfies $f(Q) = 5$ and $f(P)=0$?

Comment: Your equation for $\ell$ is correct. You already know that $f(2,3)=0$ and $f(4,0)=5$. Now, $f(\cdot)$ is supposed to preserve distances along the _whole_ line $\ell\equiv\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\,|\,y=-3x/2+6\}$. As we moved from $(2,3)$ to $(4,0)$, the value of the function increased by $5$. Therefore, the slope of $f(\cdot)$ in terms of $x$ should be $5/2$. We can thus define a linear extension of these two points by $$f(x,y)=5(x-2)/2\quad\forall(x,y)\in\ell.$$ Note that $f(\cdot)$ does not depend explicitly on $x$, since the value of $y$ is pinned down if $(x,y)$ is on the line $\ell$.

Comment: It remains to check whether $f:\ell\to\mathbb R$ is bijective and preserves distance for any pair of points on $\ell$. (Please try to do this on your own.)

Comment: Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Alex You're very welcome. :-)